# has invalid type for ‘reduction' openmp for c++

Tags: c++, openmp

I have used `openm` to parallelize my c++ code as below:

```
        int shell_num = 50, grparallel[shell_num],grbot[shell_num]; 
    double  p_x,p_y,grp[shell_num];     
   for (int f = 0; f < shell_num; f++)
    {
    grp[f] = 0;
    grparallel[f] = 0;
    grbot[f] = 0;
    }

 //some code... 
 #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+ : grp,grparallel,grbot)
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){ //some code
       for(int j = 0; j < N; j++){
         if (j==i) continue;
         double delta_x = x[i]-x[j], 
         delta_y = y[i]-y[j],
         e_dot_e = e_x[i] * e_x[j] + e_y[i] * e_y[j],  
         e_cross_e = e_x[i] * e_y[j] - e_y[i] * e_x[j];
         if (j > i)
            {  
            double fasele = sqrt(dist(x[i],y[i],x[j],y[j],L)); 
        for (int h = 0; h < shell_num; h++) //determine periodic distance between i and j is in which shel
            {
            if( L * h / 100 < fasele && fasele < L * (h + 1) / 100 )
             {grp[h]+= e_dot_e;
              double pdotr = abs(periodic(delta_x,L) * p_x + periodic(delta_y,L) * p_y)/fasele;
            if (pdotr > 0.9659)
                {
                 grparallel[h]+= 1;}else if(pdotr < 0.2588)
                    {
                    grbot[h]+= 1;
                    }
                    break;
                    }
                    }
        }
                    }
                }
```

When I run the code in terminal, there is an error:

> ‘grp’ has invalid type for ‘reduction’

The same error occurs for grparallel and grbot.
How can I remove the error?

Comment: What is your OS and compiler. Arrays for OpenMP reduction variables is not supported by all compilers. Depending on yours, you might have to switch back to using locals per-thread arrays + final accumulations to workaround the miss.

Comment: @Gilles I type 'g++ -fopenmp -std=gnu++11 -Wall -Wextra -g code.cpp -o a.out
' in the terminal to compile the code

Comment: Try adding the extend of the variables in the `reduction` clause like this: `reduction(+: grp[0:shell_num], grparallel[0:shell_num], grbot[0:shell_num])`.

Comment: It is not possible in c++ to use ":" . It is useul for matlab @Gilles

Comment: error: ‘grp’ has invalid type for ‘reduction’
  for reduction(+: grp[:shell_num], grparallel[:shell_num], grbot[:shell_num])   @Gilles this is the error in this case

Comment: you missed the `0`. This is `grp[0:shell_num]`, not `grp[:shell_num]`. The syntax is `var[start_index:extent]`.

Comment: The error didn't removed: grp’ has invalid type for ‘reduction’
 r reduction(+: grp[0:shell_num], grparallel[0:shell_num], grbot[0:shell_num])  @Gilles

Comment: Then your compiler doesn't seem to support reductions on arrays. Again which compiler on what OS? (please include exact versions)

Comment: @Gilles gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Comment: LSB Version: core-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-amd64:core-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-noarch:security-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-amd64:security-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-noarch
Distributor ID: LinuxMint
Description: Linux Mint 18 Sarah
Release: 18
Codename: sarah
 @Gilles

Comment: Array reductions for OpenMP in C and C++ is part of the standard 4.5. GCC 5 only supports OpenMP 4.0. You'll need at least GCC 6 to have OpenMP 4.5 supported.

Comment: or you can write your app in Fortran, unlike C/C++, array reduction has been there for a while.

Comment: Could you please check my new question? @GillesGouaillardet

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet it is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47426526/using-continue-inside-the-paralleld-for-loop