# Using continue inside the paralleld for loop

Tags: c++, openmp

My code looks-like as below:

```
 #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(5)
            for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
               {
                //some code
                //#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+ : S_x,S_y,S_theta)
                for(int j = 0; j < N; j++)
                  {
                    if (j==i) continue;
                     // some code
                    for(int ky = -1; ky<= 1; ky++)
                        {
                        for(int kx = -1; kx<= 1; kx++)
                           {
                           //some code
                           if (r_ij_square > l0_two)
                              { 
                              //some code
                              }
                           }
                        }
                    }
            //some code
                }
```

I'm not sure if `continue` in above code could cause any prblem or not. To avoid any problem, I have ignored second `#pragma` in above code by `//`. But I'm not still  sure if above code could cause any problem due to using `continue` or not? My question is if above code could cause problem or not, and if yes, how can I remove the problem?
When searching, I found these two sentences `loops with "restricted" continue statements can be parallelized.` or `Only an iteration of the innermost associated loop may be curtailed by a continue statement.` . But I don't know what do they mean exactly

Comment: i guess the compiler complains about a `break` but not about `continue`.
`continue` simply move to the next iteration, so other threads running other iterations are not impacted (unlike the `break` statement), so there is no issue running `continue`.

Comment: Thank you very much. So do you think I can remove comment on the second pragma? @GillesGouaillardet

Comment: When searching, I found that loops with "restricted" continue statements can be parallelized. or Only an iteration of the innermost associated loop may be curtailed by a continue statement. . But I don't know what do they mean exactly @GillesGouaillardet

Comment: my first advice is that if you do not need OpenMP nested parallelism, then do not do that, and simply parallelize the outermost loop instead.
That being said, i do not expect things go wrong if you remove the comment on the second pragma.

Comment: Yes as it is clear from the code, I have palatalized outer loop, so your suggestion is paralizing outer loop is enough. Do you know What do these sentences mean? loops with "restricted" continue statements can be parallelized. or Only an iteration of the innermost associated loop may be curtailed by a continue statement

Comment: unless your code suffers from severe imbalance, then yes, parallelizing the outermost loop is enough. where did you get this sentences from ?

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Here is the link :http://forum.openmp.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=458

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet What do you mean by  severe imbalance? I couldnt find it's definition

Comment: severe imbalance is when some iterations are way faster than others, and you end up having a bunch of threads waiting for the slow one.

Comment: +one Thank you for your comment. @GillesGouaillardet